# File not found error?

Tags: error

Okay so,
I wanted to export an 2D intro and it keeps popping up saying the file doesn't exists.
I don't know how I can fix this.

Comment: As in every "file not found" error make sure to check that directory and file mentioned by Blender exist. In most cases this happens when animation was rendered and moved or deleted from that folder. As to rendering animation make sure to check your user has privileges to write in the folder Blender is set up to use for animations. Instead of writing "watch video first" please include screenshots from the video here. This will allow others not go through links just to see what are you asking

Comment: Typing in All Caps is considered yelling. It is just rude... (http://allwomenstalk.com/12-netiquette-rules-to-remember/2). Also, please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit: You're not missing any file.

Click on the icon the arrow is pointing to.

All you have to do is change the output location to a folder on your computer of your choice.

[image]

Comment: Before I answer that you have to tell me if you have the MP4 file that it says it's missing. Please read the error, look at the name of the file it says it is missing, and then tell me if you even have that file anywhere on your computer.

Comment: Then logically you can't do anything without the missing file right? Nobody else will be able to help you either.

You need to stop. Backtrack to where you downloaded that file in the first place. You obviously missed something else and forgot to download the .mp4 file that goes along with the blender file.

This is called thinking and troubleshooting. Not to sound harsh :)

Comment: I think the uploader of that template messed up then. This might not be your fault.

Comment: I get the same error too.

Comment: You can get your free templates from here btw http://www.giyf.com/

Comment: @BolleboorMc You shouldn't use templates anyway though because everyone hates YouTube intros. It gives people a reason to close out of your video in the first few seconds. Just make a 1 second logo that fades in and out before your video. Now that's classy. Don't be gross with annoying intros.

Comment: @BolleboorMc I've edited my answer. This explains who to get the template working. I learned something new today! You weren't missing any files at all

Comment: You need to set the export format/codec and set the export location manually.